# Use of to_date or similar function in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I've a SQL template that looks like this:

```
Select a.* 
 from A a 
 inner join B b 
 on a.a1=b.b1 
 where a.a2 >= (?1) and
 a.a2 < (?2) and
 b.b2 IN ({0});
```

a2 is a DATE field. The table A is partitioned on a2 & an index exists on a2. The corresponding DB entity in Java looks like this:

```
aDb {
 Long a1;
 org.joda.DateTime a2;

 @Column(name="a2", length=7)
 @Type(type="org.joda.time.contrib.hibernate.PersistentDateTime")
 public DateTime getA2() {
  return this.a2;
 }
}
```

Since a time stamp gets sent into the query, the index is not being used. This is causing the query to take ages!

I tried to add to_date to the query & HQL doesn't support it. I can't use JPQL since I'm building the query in runtime (As can be seen by {0}).

Is there a way I can send a DATE as (?1) & (?2)

Comment: have you tried sth like this? `setParameter(1, new Date(), TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();`

Comment: You may try this hql :String hql = "select * from Book as b where b.releaseDate > :date1 and b.releaseDate < :date2";
session.createQuery(hql).setDate("date1", date1).setDate("date2", date2).list();

Comment: @Amit Garg - How will this ensure that Date gets passed?